# WF 4.5 WCF Workflow Service Application calling with REST

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, workflow-foundation-4

Want a way to call a WCF Workflow Service Application using REST instead of SOAP. I've defined a REST endpoint with custom webhttpbehavior and from that call I am trying to load the XAMLX and run it.

My first attempt fails with

```
    Expression Activity type 'CSharpReference`1' requires compilation in order to run. Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled
```

I​ found code to compile the Expression before invoking the workflow and then I get errors like.

```
    The type or namespace name 'Activities' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
```

I found some other code to set

```
 AttachableMemberIdentifier and AttachablePropertyServices
```

then I got

```
The type or namespace name 'Activities' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel'
```

​
E​ven though I'm adding the assemblyreferences for all 3 namespaces (my local solution, System.ServiceModel and System.Activities)​

The xamlx is the simple out of box one that it generates with GetData passing in an int and returns the int.ToString()

​What am I missing?

Code Following:

```
    namespace WFStarterSolution
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class RestService
    {

        static void CompileExpressions(DynamicActivity activity)
        {
            var activityName = activity.Name;

            // Split activityName into Namespace and Type.Append _CompiledExpressionRoot to the type name
            // to represent the new type that represents the compiled expressions.
            // Take everything after the last . for the type name.
            var activityType = activityName.Split('.').Last() + "_CompiledExpressionRoot";
            // Take everything before the last . for the namespace.
            var activityNamespace = string.Join(".", activityName.Split('.').Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse());

            // Create a TextExpressionCompilerSettings.
            var settings = new TextExpressionCompilerSettings
            {
                Activity = activity,
                Language = "C#",
                ActivityName = activityType,
                ActivityNamespace = activityNamespace,
                RootNamespace = null,//"CSharpExpression",
                GenerateAsPartialClass = false,
                AlwaysGenerateSource = true,
                ForImplementation = true
            };

            // Compile the C# expression.
            var results = new TextExpressionCompiler(settings).Compile();

            // Any compilation errors are contained in the CompilerMessages.
            if (results.HasErrors)
            {               
                var cm = results.CompilerMessages.Aggregate(" 
", (current, e) => current + (e.Number + " - "+e.Message + " : Line Number "+e.SourceLineNumber + "
"));
                throw new Exception("Compilation failed."+cm);
            }

            // Create an instance of the new compiled expression type.
            var compiledExpressionRoot =
                Activator.CreateInstance(results.ResultType,
                    new object[] { activity }) as ICompiledExpressionRoot;

            // Attach it to the activity.
            CompiledExpressionInvoker.SetCompiledExpressionRoot(
                activity, compiledExpressionRoot);
        }


        [OperationContract]
        public string DoWork()
        {
            // call WFService XAMLX somehow
            var filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            try
            {
                var serviceImplementation = XamlServices.Load(filepath + "WFService.xamlx");
                var service = serviceImplementation as WorkflowService;
                if (service == null)
                {
                    return "Failed";
                }
                else
                {
                    var activity = service.Body;                    
                    var operand1 = new InArgument();
                    var dyanamicActivity = new DynamicActivity { Name = "WFServiceName", Implementation = () => activity};
                    var p = new DynamicActivityProperty
                                {
                                    Name = "data",
                                    Type = typeof(InArgument),
                                    Value = operand1
                                };

                    dyanamicActivity.Properties.Add(p);
                    var impl = new AttachableMemberIdentifier(typeof(TextExpression), "NamespacesForImplementation");
                    var namespaces = new List { "WFStarterSolution" };
                    var ar = new[]
                                 { 
                                   new AssemblyReference 
                                     {
                                         Assembly = typeof (DynamicActivity).Assembly
                                     },
                                     new AssemblyReference 
                                     {                                          
                                         Assembly = typeof (RestService).Assembly
                                     },                                     
                                   new AssemblyReference 
                                     {
                                         Assembly = typeof (ServiceContractAttribute).Assembly
                                     }
                                 };
                    TextExpression.SetReferencesForImplementation(dyanamicActivity, ar);
                    AttachablePropertyServices.SetProperty(dyanamicActivity, impl, namespaces);
                    CompileExpressions(dyanamicActivity);

                    var iDict = new Dictionary() {  { "data", 45} };
                    var output = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(dyanamicActivity, iDict);

                    return "success";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message+"
"+ex.StackTrace;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE ***** 
If I add the following in to the AssemblyReference array

```
,new AssemblyReference 
{
    Assembly = typeof (WorkflowService).Assembly
}
```

, it compiles fine... but still gives the me original error of

```
    Expression Activity type 'CSharpReference`1' requires compilation in order to run. Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled
```